# Update Cursor Adapter on single row

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, android-cursoradapter

I render an UI rely on Cursor entries, meanwhile is can happen that an
update of an row happen in my `ContentProvider`, so I use
`getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` to inform
the `CursorAdapter` of this update.

The Problem is that teh Cursor gets an complete update (like an requery) instead of
just an update of this specific row. This results in an stuttering UI while scrolling
in this view.

Is there anything I miss to update the UI in an smarter way ?